# draggable element should go to the start position on confirmation false

Tags: jquery, ajax, draggable, droppable, confirmation

My code is below.

```
function editState()
{
 var b  = confirm("Are you sure?");
 $( ".usMainDef" ).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        revert:true,
        stack: ".usMainDef"
        });

        $('.inproUS').droppable(
            {

                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                accept: ".usMainDef",
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    if (!b) {

                            } else {
                        id= $(ui.draggable).prop('id');
                        var colid=$(event.target).attr('id');
                        var newid=parseInt(id);
                        $( "<div id='"+id+"' class='box usMainInp' ></div>" ).html( ui.draggable.html() ).appendTo( this).draggable( {cursor: 'move', revert:'invalid' });

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "index.php?r=workspace/changeState",
                            // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
                            data: {
                                uState:colid,
                                uID:newid

                            },
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(data){

                            },
                            failure: function(errMsg) {
                                alert(errMsg);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            });
    }
```

When I drag the element which  has 'usMainDef' class it will prompt a confirmation. If I click 'cancel' I want to go back to the earlier position.If I click 'ok' it should send the ajax request. Later part is working.My problem is when i click 'cancel' element won't move to it's starting point.how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer , finally. 
Here it is. i just want to add only the below lines. Then it work well.

```
if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                    ui.draggable.animate(ui.draggable.data().origPosition,"slow");                          
                }

else
    {
/*ajax request*/
}
```